# Tower of Babel - Rocketship?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-noach, tower-of-babel

Are there any authentic Jewish sources that  claim that the Tower of Babel was a spaceship?  I remember as a child being told by somebody that Rav Eibishitz had written something to this effect.

Comment: Relevant discussion at parshablog: [Rav Yonasan Eibeshutz's Rocket Ship](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2010/10/rav-yonasan-eibeshutzs-rocket-ship.html) and [An analysis of Rav Yonasan Eibeshitz's Space Elevator](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2010/10/analysis-of-rav-yonasan-eibeshitzs.html)

Answer (score 8):

See [here](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2010/10/rav-yonasan-eibeshutzs-rocket-ship.html) for a full explanation of Rav Yonasan Eibeshitz's idea of the generation attempting to build a tower so high it would reach beyond the gravitational pull of the Earth. Then, they planned to have a boat-like vessel atop the tower to be carried up from the Earth's winds to the moon, where they would no longer need to fear torrential rain. 
(Rav

[image]

Comment: This seems to be describing a Space Elevator more than a spaceship, but good find.

Comment: The way I understood it was that it was a very high launching pad.

Comment: @robev which is exactly what a Space Elevator is - a very high launching pad whose top is already moving at orbital velocity.

Comment: Which sefer is that picture from?

Answer (score 2):

I've heard people reference Sanhedrin 106b when mentioning it, although there doesn't seem to be any link between the two.

> א"ר ארבע מאה בעיי' בעו דואג ואחיתופל במגדל הפורח באויר
>
> Rav said, 'Doeg and Achitophel asked four hundred questions about a tower that floats in the air'

Rashi gives a number of explanations, among them:

> **במגדל הפורח באויר** - לעשות כישוף להעמיד מגדל באויר
>
> **About a tower that floats in the air** - to perform kishuf to make a tower float in the air.

I suspect that this was the source of the idea.

Comment: Migdal throughout mishnayos and talmud means a type of a box. Along with a shida and a teiva.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be referring to the Tower of Babel, as you mentioned.

Comment: @ezra That's right. But I have heard people quote it when mentioning that the *tower* of Bavel was a rocket.

Answer (score 1):

Since rocket ships are a modern invention, the concept of "building up to heaven" or "being able to go to heaven" is a spiritual or theoretical idea. It is like "aron haporeich ba-avir" (a flying box) in the talmud. As a result, the meforshim do not deal with this on the level of a *rocket ship*.

> a tower whose top shall reach unto heaven

is an expression of rebellion against Hashem, not a physical statement.

Rav Hirsch points out in [Noach 11:4](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8175#v=4&showrashi=true) that it means for the glorification of the leader and it is something that will be recognized by everyone and forever. It will be a process that will involve the entire society for generations. This is like the pyramids of Egypt (or the ziggurats of Bavel or the cathedrals of Europe).

The full quote is too long to put here so I have just summarized it.