# Exegesis and meaning of Psalms 18,10

Tags: tehilim-psalms

What is meant by: "He (G-d) mounted a cherub and flew,
gliding on the wings of the wind".

Some claim it is a spaceship-type flying craft.

I searched for rabbinic exegeses on this passage from the Psalms but found no explanation. Any ideas?

Comment: Alshich and Abarbanel say it’s referring to the keruvin in the Bais Hamikdash

Comment: If the rabbinic commentary says that God rode a cloud, would that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason there is not so much discussion on the verse in Psalms is because that chapter is extremely similar to Samuel II Ch. 22. Abarbanel there says the term refers to strong winds, based on the Medrash Rabbah. Malbim to Psalms follows this approach.

[Maimonides](https://library.alhatorah.org/?r1=Moreh_Nevukhim_1:49&s1=2) includes this verse in his discussion of angels. This is also the apparent meaning of the Targum (Aramaic translation to Bible.)

Either way, the verse is a metaphor saying G-d uses angels and/or wind as his messengers. Saying this verse refers to spaceships is just being fanciful.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/86349/759

Comment: @DoubleAA That was for people.